# Dovecot SSL - IMAP works, SMTP fails

Tags: smtp, ssl-certificate, dovecot

I'm setting up a small mail server using postfix+dovecot. When running `oppenssl s_client -connect mail.myserver.com:993` (IMAP), the server's certificate is displayed and I'm able to get an email client to connect fine.

However, when I change the port to `25` (SMTP), I get the error
`SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`, and no certificate is returned.

From my research, it seems that the protocols and ciphers allowed in the `10-ssl.conf` file might be the issue, but I've tried so many combinations and I still get the same error. This is what they are at the moment:

```
ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 !SSLv3 !SSLv2
ssl_cipher_list = HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1.0:!aNULL:!MD5
```

How can I get the server to return the certificate on the SMTP port?

Comment: dovecot does not do SMTP, that's the job of the mail transport agent (e.g. postfix, exim, ...). What MTA are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Postfix + Dovecot setup has two different server software performing different roles:

- Dovecot in your configuratoin is a *mail storage server*, responsible for IMAP. Additionally, Dovecot [provides SASL authentication](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL) for Postfix. The configuration file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf` is for Dovecot alone, and therefore it only affects IMAP with `STARTTLS` on port 143 and IMAPS on port 993.
- Postfix is the *mail delivery agent* (MTA) responsible for SMTP, whether it's for other MTAs on TCP port 25, for *message submission* with `STARTTLS` on port 587 or SMTPS on port 465. The main configuration files for Postfix are `main.cf` and `master.cf` under `/etc/postfix/`.

You can only test IMAPS `993` & SMTPS `465` using `oppenssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:465`. For testing `STARTTLS` on SMTP ports `25` & `587` and IMAP port `143` you need to use:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.example.com:25
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.example.com:587
openssl s_client -starttls imap -connect mail.example.com:143
```

There's also several websites and tools for testing, discussed in a Security Stack Exchange [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58857/test-starttls-configuration-of-smtp-server). For configuring TLS in Postfix, see [Postfix TLS Support](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html). The [Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL) documentation also has an example for configuring *submission*. In addition, you need to add TLS parameters to your `main.cf`.

Answer (score 3):

Port 25 do not use SSL by default. Client have to run `STARTTLS` command to begin the negotiations with server about cryptography. In opposite IMAPS on the port 993 begins SSL negotiations immediately on connect. You have to configure and try the SMTPS on the port 465 that acts exactly like IMAPS on 993.

Comment: Please note SMTPS on port 465 is considered deprecated

Answer (score 2):

To test services, such as SMTP, that run both the clear text protocol as well as an TLS encrypted version of that protocol *on the same TCP port*, you need to instruct openssl to negotiate the TLS protocol upgrade with [STARTTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS)  and the [`-starttls protocol`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-s_client.html) switch.

Depending on the openssl version, s_client supports a number of different protocols:

> **`-starttls protocol`**
>     send the protocol-specific message(s) to switch to TLS for communication.  **`protocol`** is a keyword for the intended protocol.  Currently, the only supported keywords are "smtp", "pop3", "imap",
>              "ftp", "xmpp", "xmpp-server", "irc", "postgres", "lmtp", "nntp", "sieve" and "ldap".

So test your Postfix mail server with:

```
oppenssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.example.com:25
```